# What is the correct way to call a custom theme function in Drupal?

Tags: drupal

I have a custom theme we'll call "MyTheme."  In the template.php file, I have a function named "MyTheme_MyFunction."

In my page.tpl.php, should I be able to do this:

```
<?php print theme('MyFunction'); ?>
```

Or, do I have to do this:

```
<?php print MyTheme_Function(); ?>
```

I know the latter works, but shouldn't the former work too?

Comment: The former will work only when the hook_theme() function is implemented for the function above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first definitely works, but for it to do so you need to tell Drupal about your theme function in hook_theme() (i.e. MyTheme_theme() in your theme's template.php) and then clear your theme cache.

See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_theme/6 for more details.

Answer (score 4):

### Use theme()

You should always call your theme functions via the `theme()` function, as you show in your first example: `theme('MyFunction')`. If you don't do this, you're crippling the Drupal theme system and not allowing other module developers to effectively override your output.

When writing your own theme functions, don't forget to use `hook_theme` (explained [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7)) to register your theme function with the theme registry. If you don't do this, calling `theme('MyFunction')` won't work. Never hurts to clear caches after initially registering the function, either.

### Example of why it's important

For example, in your theme's template.php, you can define your own `theme_image` function to override how Drupal core handles images. You'd name your function `name_of_theme_image` and get to work overriding what it returns. If `theme_image` weren't always called as `theme('image')`, you wouldn't be able to leverage this overriding behavior, because `theme()` acts as the single point of entry and delegator of theme functions. The same is true of your theme functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the preopreocess page hook

`function themename_preprocess_page(&$variables) { 

$variables['custom_name'] = function_name(); 

}`

Then in the page.tpl.php you can use 
This is how the variables are passed to the tpl files.

Similarly for node.tpl.php you can use

`function themename_preprocess_node(&$variables) {`

}